# Find numbers with same number of divisors

Tags: ruby, time-limit-exceeded

I tried to resolve this task:

> The integers 14 and 15, are contiguous (1 the difference between them,
>   noticeable) and have the same number of divisors.
>
> ```
> 14 ----> 1, 2, 7, 14 (4 divisors)
> 15 ----> 1, 3, 5, 15 (4 divisors)
> ```
>
> The next pair of contiguous integers with this property is 21 and 22.
>
> ```
> 21 -----> 1, 3, 7, 21 (4 divisors)
> 22 -----> 1, 2, 11, 22 (4 divisors)
> ```
>
> We have 8 pairs of integers below 50 having this property, they are:
>
> ```
> [[2, 3], [14, 15], [21, 22], [26, 27], [33, 34], [34, 35], [38, 39], [44, 45]]
> ```
>
> Let's see now the integers that have a difference of 3 between them.
>   There are seven pairs below 100:
>
> ```
> [[2, 5], [35, 38], [55, 58], [62, 65], [74, 77], [82, 85], [91, 94]]
> ```
>
> Let's name, diff, the difference between two integers, next and prev,
>   (diff = next - prev) and nMax, an upper bound of the range.
>
> We need a particular function, count_pairsInt(), that receives two
>   arguments, diff, and nMax and outputs the amount of pairs of integers
>   that fulfill this property, all of them being smaller (not less or
>   equal) than nMax.
>
> Let's see it more clearly with examples.
>
> ```
> count_pairs_int(1, 50) -----> 8 (See case above)
> count_pairs_int(3, 100) -----> 7 (See case above)
> ```

Source: [codewars.com](https://www.codewars.com/kata/find-numbers-with-same-amount-of-divisors/)

My code:

```
def count_pairs_int(diff, n_max)
  (1..n_max - diff).select { |n| getDivisors(n) == getDivisors(n + diff) }.count
end

def getDivisors(num)
  (1..num).select { |n| (num % n).zero? }.count
end
```

There is a problem with time of execution code:

> The process terminated. It took longer than 8000ms to complete

Initial tests are passed (first 10). Any ideas on how I can optimize the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not interested in the divisors themselves, only how many there are.
This can be calculated if the prime factors are known. For example, 12 has two 2' s and one 3 (12 = 2*2*3). The divisors are the product of 0,1 or 2 2's and 0 or 1 3's. So six divisors. The primes themselves are irrelevant, what matters is how many of each there are.

If only Ruby shipped with a method to do this prime division...

```
require 'prime' # delivers the prime_division method

class Integer
  def tau
    self.prime_division.map(&:last).inject(1){|prod,i| prod *= i+1}
  end
end

def count_pairsInt(diff,  nMax )
  (1..nMax-diff).count{|n| n.tau == (n+diff).tau}
end
```

Note: Probably this can be faster by memoizing (storing) the last `diff` tau (divisor count) calculations, to avoid calculating them twice.

Comment: thank you @steenslag, you are great. In count_pairseInt should be range (1..nMax - diff).

Comment: @ŁukaszKorol yes, nasty trap I fell into.

Comment: Typically it will be much faster, when computing a function on prime factors over a wide range of consecutive integers, to use a sieve approach and compute them all together rather than individually.  E.g. for every fifth number, push 5 onto its list of prime factors.

Answer (score 0):

A glaring performance issue I see is the use of `count` for both methods. Count will enumerate over each element in the array to return the final count and [should be avoided if possible](http://batsov.com/articles/2014/02/17/the-elements-of-style-in-ruby-number-13-length-vs-size-vs-count/). Instead, you could use `size`. This alone is a simple change that should greatly improve your execution time.

Your updated code should look like this:

```
def count_pairs_int(diff, n_max)
  (1..n_max - diff).select { |n| getDivisors(n) == getDivisors(n + diff) }.size
end

def getDivisors(num)
  (1..num).select { |n| (num % n).zero? }.size
end
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, a process still terminated.